# EF Core Compiled Model cache expiration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

For the first cold query ef core compiles the entire model that usually have a high cost propotional to the model size and complexity. Can this cache be invalidated when there is no request to the server and no query is executed for 20 minutes or so using dbcontext and we need to again bear that cost?

Comment: Have you looked at compiled models in EF Core 6?

Comment: Yes @ErikEJ i have tested my app with ef core 6 using compiled models. The first query execution time drastically improved due to there is no cost to generate the model views. My app is running on production currently using ef core 3 and i am facing an issue after 20 minutes when there is no request to the server when i open the site it takes around 14 sec return a simple page with simple query.

Comment: I am wondering it might be due to cached model is busted, and its again trying to generate the model views before execution of the query

Comment: I have already set the app pool idle timeout to 700 minutes so that might not be the cause. After 20 minutes of idle first request takes 14sec and subsequent takes less than 300 ms.

Comment: Create a process to keep your web app alive